# How to connect to the database in Docker in my case?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to my postgres through docker containers. I have read
a lots of posts but still can't seem to resolve it.

I ran the following command.

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypw -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

after that, I do `docker inspect $(containerID)`

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "773de825919cb75482af47b85b1804f96a32bc6e9951cc0ea80752f880789717",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/773de825919c",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "29c872cb1487519a8f605f7ba371e5ce84c2b163140babbb981ace8a12a273cd",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "9d69c3e1dfa70572306fbe6dd14ed91d7ee96796deb27057b1c2992f573875f9",
                    "EndpointID": "29c872cb1487519a8f605f7ba371e5ce84c2b163140babbb981ace8a12a273cd",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
```

My understanding is I can use the `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"` to connect to the DB

so I do

```
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

However, I am getting operation timeout error and not be able to login to postgres.

Error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentioned how you run docker. If you use it on your Workstation like Docker for OSx you have to use "localhost" for connection:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

If you run the container on a Docker VM or on a remote host, you need the external interface IP in your local network.

```
psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Further you have to verify, if PostgreSQL is configured to allow remote connection, for this check "`pg_hba.conf`" and add

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

and change the `listen_addresses` to `listen_addresses='*'` in: /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf

Please note: this setup is for testing only, and opens a hole in your database configuration.